# How would I set a long long to a huge number without a warning?

Tags: c++, initialization, overflow, warnings, long-long

Right now, I have

```
long long x = 1 << 60;
cout << x << endl;
```

and I know that the range for long long can be all the way up to `2^64`, but for some reason when I execute the piece of code, it gives me a warning that says "`left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow].`"

In addition, `0` is printed to the screen, which is obviously not what I wanted.

I tried putting the literal "ll" after it, but I don't know where I should put it:

```
long long x = (1 << 60)ll;
long long x = (1 << 60ll);
```

and none of them work

Could anyone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the correct literal type: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: @NeilButterworth I tried that, but where should I put it...after the 60? after the 1? after the parenthesis?

Comment: Since you seem to be trying things more or less at random, note that there are **three** places you could add `ll` in `(1 << 60)`; you only tried two of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common mistake to expect for this expression:

```
long long x = 1 << 60;
```

that type of left side would affect calculations on the right side. It is not, result of `1 << 60` converted to type on the left, but it does not affect calculation of `1 << 60` itself. So proper solution is to change type of `1`:

```
long long x = static_cast<long long >( 1 ) << 60;
```

or

```
long long x = 1LL << 60;
```

or even

```
auto x = 1LL << 60;
```